# Rails - Simple Form - Not loading class option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css, simple-form

I'm having some troubles when I want to change the class of a form.
I have this partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@activity) do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar',:class=>"btn success" %>

<% end %>
```

In the browser the form label has class="simple_form activity"

According to Simple Form documentation, I can change the class by doing this

```
<%= simple_form_for(@activity, :defaults=>{:class=>"my_class"}) do |f| %>
```

But nothing is happening, what is wrong?

JavierQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use:

```
:html => { :class => "btn success"}
```

Instead of:

```
:class=>"btn success"
```

Comment: Well, actually the class of the button works :). The problem was with the form. I tried what you said and it works ..... but in my form. Thanks